# Which is the better approach to generate XBRL file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xbrl

I need to generate XBRL files using data from database. These XBRLs will live generate in our backend (Node.js)

I don't found any npm module to generate to XBRL from a javascript object I just found only one module to parse XBRL to JSON. So I think I need write some useful to help me with this task

So, Which is the better approach? I'm thinking in write a template, then I'll need iterate over my javascript object and fill the template with JSON's properties

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking for existing XBRL processors, as some may exist that are compatible with node.js (I am not sure, but it may be), and build on top.

Designing an XBRL processor from scratch in a new language, which many actually end up doing, sometimes without being aware of it, takes a lot of efforts to get everything right beyond a "quick" implementation, because there is much more to it than simply parsing XML.

Answer (score 0):

you can  setup opensource XBRL server and access it via REST API from Node.js or invoke it from command line using Node.js

Comment: one of the implementations is here http://arelle.org/documentation/api-web-services/